# loop on the rows in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in Excel. My question is: How can I get the first row of each row in this loop and print the output.

Input Column and Row value is like this:

```
    col1  col2   col3

    1    test    abc

    2    tests   dfg

    3    gtd     gdd
```

Output like this.

```
(col1,col2,col3)('1','test','abc');
(col1,col2,col3)('2','tests','dfg');
(col1,col2,col3)('3','gtd','gdd');
```

The Code that I am working on is

```
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 3 To LastCol
            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j)) & Cells(i, j) > 0 = True Then
              vaString = vaString & Cells(i, j)
            End If
            If j <> LastCol Then vaString = vaString & ","
            If j = LastCol Then vaString = vaString
        Next j
            myString = myString                  
    Next i
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your parameters I will assume your data starts from cell C1. Change the first few lines if otherwise.

```
Sub Testing()
Dim FirstRow As Integer, FirstCol As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer
FirstRow = 1
FirstCol = 3
LastRow = 4
LastCol = 5

Dim arrStr() As String
Dim strFirstRow As String
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "C:\..." ' Path of your choice
Open strPath For Append As #1

ReDim arrStr(FirstCol To LastCol)
For j = FirstCol To LastCol
    arrStr(j) = CStr(Cells(FirstRow, j))
Next j
strFirstRow = "(" & Join(arrStr, ",") & ")"

For i = FirstRow + 1 To LastRow
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, FirstCol).Value) Then
        If Cells(i, FirstCol).Value > 0 Then
            ReDim arrStr(FirstCol To LastCol)
            For j = FirstCol To LastCol
                arrStr(j) = "'" & CStr(Cells(i, j)) & "'" 
            Next j
            Debug.Print strFirstRow & "(" & Join(arrStr, ",") & ");"
            Print #1, strFirstRow & "(" & Join(arrStr, ",") & ");"
        End If
    End If
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: bluk ,Thanks it work. With is there any way to add single quotes like in the new update question also how to write the values to a txt file would you help me in that.

Comment: Edited that for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather simple example making use of array variables:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change according to your sheetname
    arr1 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:C1").Value2))
    arr2 = .Range("A2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    str1 = "(" & Join(arr1, ",") & ")"
    For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        str2 = "(" & Join(Array(arr2(x, 1), arr2(x, 2), arr2(x, 3)), ",") & ")" & ";"
        Debug.Print str1 & str2 'Do something with the full string
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

[image]